# Galois connection between subsets of morphisms and subsets of objects

Tags: category-theory

In any category does there exist a covariant Galois connection between subsets of morphisms and
subsets of objects? If yes, in a certain sense, it is possible to describe specific classes of morphisms by suitable full subcategories of the starting category.

Comment: Yes, there is always a trivial monotone Galois connection between posets with top/bottom: the left adjoint sends everything to the bottom element and the right adjoint sends everything to the top element.

Comment: And if $\mathfrak{C}$ is any category and $\mathfrak{O}$ is a subclass of objects closed under retracts, is there a suitable class of morphisms which are in Galois connection with $\mathfrak{O}$? How to find such a connection? Is there a way of generalizing for any specific subclass of objects?